# integrating not explicitly?

Tags: calculus, integration

Let

$$f(x)=\int_1^x\frac{\log(t)}{t+1}dt$$ if $x>0$.

Compute $f(x)+f(1/x)$

I tried to calculate integrals explicitly but obviously failed. How should I approach this problem? Hints are appreciated.

Comment: Try substituting $t\to 1/s$ in one of the two integrals.

Comment: My own first impulse would be to differentiate $f(x)+f(1/x)$ and hope that things simplify, so I could integrate it back. Haven't tried it, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Performing the substitution $t\to1/s$ leads to
$$
f(x)+f(1/x) = \int_1^x{\frac{\log t}{t+1}dt} - \int_1^x{\frac{-\log s}{1/s+1}\frac{1}{s^2}ds} = \int_1^x{\frac{\log t}{t}dt}.
$$

This integral is easily evaluated to give $(\log x)^2/2$.

Comment: just brilliant! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$\displaystyle \dfrac{1}{s(1+s)}=\dfrac{1}{s}-\dfrac{1}{1+s}.$$

Using the substitution $s=\dfrac{1}{t},$ as Eckhard suggested,  we have
$$\displaystyle f(x)=\int\limits_1^x\frac{\ln{t}}{t+1}dt=\int\limits_1^{\frac{1}{x}}\dfrac{-\ln{s}}{1+\dfrac{1}{s}}\left(-\dfrac{1}{s^2} \right)\; ds=\\
= \int\limits_1^{\frac{1}{x}}{\dfrac{\ln{s}}{s(1+s)}}\; ds = \int\limits_1^{\frac{1}{x}}{\dfrac{\ln{s}}{s}}\; ds - \int\limits_1^{\frac{1}{x}}{\dfrac{\ln{s}}{1+s}}\; ds =\\ 
= \dfrac{1}{2}\int\limits_1^{\frac{1}{x}}{d({\ln}^2{s})} -f\left(\dfrac{1}{x} \right).$$
Therefore, 
$$f(x)+f\left(\dfrac{1}{x} \right)=\dfrac{1}{2}\int\limits_1^{\frac{1}{x}}{d({\ln}^2{s})}=\dfrac{{\ln}^2{x}}{2}.$$

Comment: thank you for the answer :)